# Using Interactive Telnet Menus from PHP?

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssh, telnet

So we've got a web app at work that we're working on migrating.

The new version is based on Zend Framework, and we're gradually moving it over from this really odd little ASP classic app written in Jscript, that comes with it's own set of terminal clients that actually need to be installed on the client machine in order to work.

The reason we need the terminal clients is because we need to click on a link in a web page, and that opens up the terminal apps which log into remote systems, sometimes over two and three steps to obtain information which is sent back to the terminal client, which they then copy and paste into another application, which is processed by a perl script, and sent to the database that the first app uses.

This process is painful.

What I want to do is use ssh programmatically, to log into a remote device, in this case a router in another city, and then use telnet from there to navigate to another app that uses a series of moderately complex telnet menus (I think this is the sticking point) to navigate to the data that's needed.

There are some extremely well rounded php programmers on stack overflow, and I thought I would post here to see if anyone had solved this kind of problem before using PHP and/or Zend Framework.

When I searched for this topic on the site, I was unable to find a solution that fit the problem.

Is there a library or set of libraries I can use to do this job?

Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching this topic for a bit, and have not tried any of these solutions myself, but here is what I have found so far in my research:

https://github.com/graze/telnet-client

https://github.com/jnorell/Net_Telnet

https://github.com/farzadghanei/POLlib

http://www.geckotribe.com/php-telnet/